# Use doxygen to ^create^ README.md?

Tags: doxygen

Many people document applications in the source files themselves, e.g. https://github.com/docopt/docopt.cpp .  In the spirit of DRY (don't repeat yourself), I would like source documentation to appear in my README.md on GitHub (auto-generated from the source.) I see many user-community questions about including README.md in output documentation, but nothing about going the other way, src documentation -> README.md.  doxygen seems like the tool that should own this space, but has no output formatters for markdown files.

Does it make sense to anybody else to create an output formatter for markdown?

Comment: I have added this question to the list of doxygen issues as well:  https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/9350

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it does make sense, and has been proposed before, as well as some bolt-on solutions developed:  https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6760